# Android HttpPost not working with python CGI server

Tags: python, android, cgi, http-post

I'm buliding an android app and need to submit data to my python CGI server. I'm usually pulling data off the server with HttpGet and all those calls work correctly and quickly. When I try to push data with HttpPost, the program hangs indefinitely until I long press the return button on the emulator and force quit the program. The CGI server seems to start the script but doesn't return until I force quit the android app. When the CGI script returns, it says `CGI script exited OK` but it hasn't done anything.

At the moment I'm executing the request in the UI thread. I know it should be done in an AsyncTask but I want a solution before a try a good solution.

I've spent 3 days trying different things and looking at forums with no luck. I'd really appreciate suggestions. Here's the relevant part of my Android code:

```
private final String serverIP = "10.0.2.2";

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
String URI = "http://"+serverIP+":8000/cgi-bin/test.py?order_submit=0";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URI);

List<NameValuePair> kvPairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
kvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "bob"));
kvPairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surname", "the builder"));

try {
    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to set Entity");
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(kvPairs, HTTP.UTF_8));

    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to Post");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);

    Log.i(TAG, "execute done");
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().closeExpiredConnections();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
}
```

which outputs the following in LogCat:

`INFO/App:(534): Trying to set Entity`
`INFO/App:(534): Trying to Post`
`ERROR/App:(534): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: The operation timed out`

My Python CGI server script is as follows:

```
import os, sys, cgi, csv
import cgitb #CGI error backtracer
cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

if "order_submit" in form:    
    ofile = open(os.getcwd() + "/Forms/Output/foo.csv", "wb")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(["Name", form["name"].value])
    writer.writerow(["Surname", form["surname"].value])
    ofile.close()
```

After the Android app request has timed out, foo.csv still does not exist. The same is true even if the **if** part of the script contains the following, and doesn't use the CGI form at all:

```
if "order_submit" in form:    
    ofile = open(os.getcwd() + "/Forms/Output/foo.csv", "wb")
    writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(["Name", "harry"])
    ofile.close()
```

After the `httpclient.execute(post);` , this is the order of events:
App: `httpclient.execute(post);`
CGI server: `POST /cgi-bin/test.py?order_submit=0 HTTP/1.1" 200`
CGI server: starts the 2nd python script
*a few second's waiting...*
App: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: The operation timed out`
Python Script: creates the correct dummy file
CGI server: `CGI script exited OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5000);
```

to

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, timeout);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, timeout);
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

and it works fine now. I don't think I changed anything else. The `BasicHttpParams` must initialise something that the `DefaultHttpClient` doesn't, which is strange because the way I've been doing it works fine for `HttpGet`.

Answer (score 0):

The error sounds like the given IP is not reachable or port 8000 is blocked by the ISP or firewalled.

Comment: I edited my post and put the server IP in. It's the emulator's way of connecting to the machine's localhost where the CGI server is running. I disabled my firewall and the same behaviour happens.

Comment: Can you open the URL with your android webbrowser?

Comment: I can. The android browser shows a white screen (as it should, I think). I'm using the 2nd python CGI script I gave as a dummy to check it's running. The file is created with the correct data, so the script is running. (also confirmed by the CGI server)